# Admob integration with iphone

Tags: iphone, admob

i have integrated Admob with ios to view adbanners in my app
Application works nicely with the simmulator. (Ad bar also)

But when im tryng to run the application with the ios device. app crashes.

any solution for this??????

Comment: In which device and iOS you are doing testing?

Comment: iphone 4 , version 4.2.1

Comment: x code version 4.0.2 . ios 4.3

Comment: Can you give us some device logs or log output to help us narrow down the crash?

Comment: the problem is thr is not crash logs available.. just the app crashes.